# Nomenclature of alkenoic acids - which group has priority: the alkene or the acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Right, how do you systematically name them? Also, do you number them from the double bond end or the Carboxyl end?

Ie would it be something like.  2-methyl Hept-3-enoic acid?

Scuse the bad question and I made up the example, sorry! I'm really confused!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The carboxylic acid moiety takes precedence over the alkene moiety, so the molecule has to be numbered starting from the carboxylic acid carbon. Hence, [methacrylic acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methacrylic_acid), for example, has the systematic IUPAC name of 2-methylpropenoic acid.